# Regular expression parameters string

Tags: regex

How i can cut in my string this

```
&ertert&User=3435&5454&Parameters=asasasa
```

I want to see only 3435
I have this already , but i don't know how to cut only 3435

```
&User=(\d+)
```

Comment: Do you want specifically 3435, or do you want the first set of numbers?

Comment: Just extract the number from the capturing group.

Comment: What you did should work. How do you retrieve the result at the end ? Usually, the result of a regex matching is an array with first element the entire matched pattern and next all the captured groups.

Comment: yes i want only numbers or text after &User=, but only that that text until next &. For example &ertert&User=3435&LALAL&Parameters=asasasa only 3435 , but this could be also text not just numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use lookaheads and behinds provided you've got their support as you've not mentioned the language.

```
/(?<=User=).+?(?=&)/
```

The above regex will only match `3435`

The lookbehind `(?<=User=)` is to make sure the number what we are trying to match is preceded with the token provided in the look behind. In this case `User=`

Comment: doesn't work. I need this for ms sql .For example &ertert&User=3435&LALAL&Parameters=asasasa only 3435 , but this could be also text not just numbers

Comment: try here http://www.regexr.com/. Put my string and try yours regex. For me it doesn't work

Comment: @John what's wrong with printing the group index 1?